# How to add new roles in drupal 7?

Tags: users

Drupal by defaults gives us three roles

1. Administrator
2. Authenticated users
3. Anonymous user

Can i add a new roles in it? Like:

- suscriber
- trusted customer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

1. Go to "Home » Administration » People » Permissions"
2. Select the roles shown at the top right
3. Add a new role using the input textbox at the bottom

Your role will be created.