# How do I check the logged-in user username/password/role using a function to validate them?

Tags: authentication-authorization

I am allowing users to register an account on my site. They get a specific role using `user_save()`.

When they log in for the first time, I have to verify the login credentials.

Is there a function to verify the login credentials?
Is there a function to get the user roles?

Comment: But Drupal already takes care about checking username and password on login. And it's permission system already takes care about restricting user from seeing certain content which only admin is allowed to see. It looks like you are reinventing the wheel now - why would you? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am providing the registration to public user ... I will be assigning roles to each user when they are registering. Now after registration when they are logging in [not using Drupal back end but in my login html form] as in normal Login I need to check un/pwd/role ... each role has different view for the website

Comment: But why are you avoiding Drupal's login form? You can alter it with hooks and still use built-in, proven and tested routines.

Comment: I tried but had lot of UI issue so I thought it is better to go with this ... which is recommended according to you and why ?... sorry for asking so many question ..I am newbie in drupal

Comment: Long story short: If you don't want to use Drupal's user and content management, it would be simpler just skipping Drupal altogether and coding from scratch. If you want / need Drupal, alter it's forms, but use them, and Drupal's built-in mechanisms. Recreating parts of Drupal to work with already existing ones will be a huge pain in posterior.

Comment: @Mołot : Thanks ... we do need Drupal especially for the various roles, do you any blogs or question which can help me for this I already tried some you can see my question here ... http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/123778/how-to-assign-roles-in-my-own-registration-form-in-drupal-7 .... but that did not work too well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To check login credentials in Drupal 6&7:

```
$uid = user_authenticate($username, $password);
```

[In Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/node/2214507):

```
// Inject user.auth service..
$uid = $this->userAuth->authenticate($username, $password);
// or
$uid = \Drupal::service('user.auth')->authenticate($username, $password);
```

To check roles:

```
/**
 * Check User roles
 * @param $role
 * @param null $user
 * @return bool
 */
function user_has_role($roles, $user = NULL) {
  if ($user == NULL) {
    global $user;
  }
  if (!is_array($roles)) {
    $roles = array($roles);
  }
  if (count(array_intersect($roles, $user->roles))) {
    return TRUE;
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$username = 'Username';
$pass = 'Password';

$uid = user_authenticate($username, $pass);

user_login_submit(array(), $uid); 
$load_user = user_load($uid);

if (in_array('role_name', $load_user->roles)) {
  // Add functionality that you want to do like if you want to redirect or anything else
}
```