# How to manually check if a username and password is correct?

Tags: 8, users

There are a lot of answers on how to log in as a specific user. But I can't find any answer on how to check if the username and password is valid without logging in. I want to be able to do something like this:

```
$username = "bla@bla.com"
$password = "blablabla"

$valid = checkIfValidDetails($username, $password);
```

I simply want $valid = true if the username and password is correct, and false if not.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal 6 and 7

```
user_authenticate($username, $password);
```

Drupal 8

```
// Inject user.auth service..
$uid = $this->userAuth->authenticate($username, $password);
// or
$uid = \Drupal::service('user.auth')->authenticate($username, $password);
```

Source: [How to check logged in user username/password/role using Drupal function for validation](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/126013/how-to-check-logged-in-user-username-password-role-using-drupal-function-for-val)